# UART DMA Buffer Problem

Tags: stm32, c, dma

I have a problem with DMA receive function, when I stop the         HAL_UART_DMAStop(&huart2); dma buffer doesnt clean, so I see the all data in buffer, ( I am using NORMAL BUFFER)
when I send 17 byte data every time, I want to see just 17 byte data but I see like this:

```
    Length 17
    
    11 22 33 44 55 ......AA BB
    
    Length 34 ( Bold one new data first 17 byte data old data)
    
    11 22 33 44 55 .... AA BB **CC DD EE FF ..... AA BB**
until length 500 byte
```

How is possible how can I solve this, I expect like this:

```
Length 17
11 22 33 44 55 ..... AA BB
Length 17 
CC DD EE FF .... AA BB
```

I am using this function receive data with stm32f4

HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)dma_rx_buf,DMA_BUF_SIZE);

DMA_BUF_SIZE = 500

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  uint16_t currentValueCNDTR = __HAL_DMA_GET_COUNTER(huart->hdmarx);
  if((currentValueCNDTR != DMA_BUF_SIZE))
  {
    HAL_UART_DMAStop(&huart2);
    bufferLength =  DMA_BUF_SIZE - currentValueCNDTR;
    printf("Length %d\n",bufferLength);

    for(j = 0; j < bufferLength; j++)
    {
      printf("%02x ",dma_rx_buf[dummyCounter]);
    }
        HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)dma_rx_buf,DMA_BUF_SIZE);
  
 }
}
```

When I detect the IDLE line in UART2 global interrupt I set to receiveflag = 1

```
  void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 0 */
        /* UART IDLE Interrupt */
            if((__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_IDLE) != RESET))   
        {    
          receveFlag = 1;
          __HAL_UART_CLEAR_IDLEFLAG(&huart2);
    
        }
    }
```

And in my main loop I call the function like this:

```
int main()
{
HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)dma_rx_buf,DMA_BUF_SIZE);
while(1)
{
       if((recevieFlag == 1U))
        {
          hdma_usart2_rx.XferCpltCallback(&hdma_usart2_rx);
          receiveFlag = 0;
        } 

}
}
```

**EDIT**
I noticed something, If I call the  again

```
 **HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)dma_rx_buf,DMA_BUF_SIZE);**
     HAL_UART_DMAStop(&huart2);
      HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)dma_rx_buf,DMA_BUF_SIZE);
```

after     HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)dma_rx_buf,DMA_BUF_SIZE); dma buffer reset, why the once stop and receive is not enough?